Pipe Hanging Support with Tee slab
How can I install pipe hanging supports with double tee slab as slab thickness is not enough to install a wedge anchor?

probably shouldn't hang things off a slab too thin to put a redhead in.

Yes I thought so too but the design tells us to install hanging supports with this configuration. Is there any other way to do so?

Through holed and steel plates on each side bolter together.
